# KeyedCollection is a collection of what?

Tags: c#, collections, keyedcollection

I want to create a method that would iterate through a keyed collection. I want to make sure that my method support iteration of any collection that extends the `KeyedCollection<string, Collection<string>>`

Here's the method:

```
public void IterateCollection(KeyedCollection<string, Collection<string>> items)
{
    foreach (??? item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + item.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + item.Value);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work obviously because I don't know which type should replace the question marks in the loop. I cannot simply put `object` or `var` because I need to call the `Key` and `Value` properties later on in the loop body. What is the type that I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider using ReSharper or any other code assisting tool in your aid. ReSharper will give you an option to specify the type explicitly when you use var. So you could've solved this by a simple key combination in ReSharper (alt-enter)

Comment: And if you call dynamic to the rescue?
In your case, item will be Collection<string> wich is what KeyedCollection will return, KeyedCllection will return always <Titem>, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` implements `ICollection<TItem>`, so in this case you'd use:

```
foreach(Collection<string> item in items)
```

That's what `var` would give you as well. You don't *get* key/value pairs in `KeyedCollection` - you just get the values.

Is it possible that `KeyedCollection` really isn't the most appropriate type for you to be using?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I do need the collection of key/value pairs, so I am wrong for using `KeyedCollection`. Could you please recommend me a class that is as abstract as possible, but could serve my purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @Boris: Just `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The item type is going to be `Collection<String>` by definition of the enumerator of `KeyedCollection`.  You can't arbitrarily decide on using an appropriate type so that you get both `Key` and `Value` if the iteration doesn't support it, which it doesn't in this case.  Note that using the explicit type and `var` are exactly identical.

If you want both `Key` and `Value` available in iteration, you need to use the `Dictionary<string, Collection<string>>` type.

Comment: mellamokb, thanks for the clarification on explicit types and vars. Could you recommend a class that might serve my purpose? I need a collection of key/value pairs. Thanks!